# catch NoSuchPropertyException excetion when use 'choose' item inside the 'foreach' item

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I want to insert batch db records into mysql, so I write mybatis mapping xml using `foreach` and `choose` items.

However, it gives me `NoSuchPropertyException` when I run the test function.
The mapping xml code is like this:

```
<insert id="insertIntervalConfig" parameterType="java.util.List" useGeneratedKeys="true"  keyProperty="id">
    INSERT INTO
        <include refid="tableName"></include>
        <include refid="insertFields"></include>
    VALUES
        <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" separator=",">
            (
                <choose><when test="item.appId == null">0</when><otherwise>#{item.appId, jdbcType=INTEGER}</otherwise></choose>,
                <choose><when test="item.stageId == null">0</when><otherwise>#{item.stageId, jdbcType=INTEGER}</otherwise></choose>,
                <choose><when test="item.intervalType == null">0</when><otherwise>#{item.intervalType, jdbcType=INTEGER}</otherwise></choose>,
                <choose><when test="item.accountTypeName == null">''</when><otherwise>#{item.accountTypeName, jdbcType=VARCHAR}</otherwise></choose>,
                <choose><when test="item.accountTypeCode == null">''</when><otherwise>#{item.accountTypeCode, jdbcType=VARCHAR}</otherwise></choose>,
                #{item.accountMin, jdbcType=INTEGER}, #{item.accountMax, jdbcType=INTEGER},
                <choose><when test="item.displayName== null">''</when><otherwise>#{item.displayName, jdbcType=VARCHAR}</otherwise></choose>,
                <choose><when test="item.sequenceId == null">0</when><otherwise>#{item.sequenceId, jdbcType=INTEGER}</otherwise></choose>
            )
        </foreach>

</insert>
```

---

and my test function is like this

```
List<IntervalConfigDO> configList = new ArrayList<IntervalConfigDO>();
configList.add(config1);
configList.add(config2);
intervalConfigDao.insertIntervalConfig(configList);
```

the detail exception is:

> org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error evaluating expression 'item.appId == null'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.ognl.NoSuchPropertyException

I find that it works when i remove the `choose` item, but I don't know why, could someone give some tips?

Comment: this problem finally be dealt with adding @Data annotation to the object class (IntervalConfigDO)

Comment: Consider answering your own question, it is not only allowed but encouraged because it will help others